# HTML5 Video Slideshow not working on Mac FF or Safari

Tags: javascript, css, html, video, slideshow

Here's my jsfiddle for review: http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Nq8/81/

The code works perfect in Chrome on my Mac. Firefox and Safari don't. I had another contributor who did the code edits, and he says everything is working on Windows. Please review and let me know if you see something that I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

js:
    $(function () {

```
var $videos = $('.video'),
    numVideos = $videos.length,
    counter = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    ++counter;
    var $currentVideo = $('.video[data-state="playing"]'),
        $nextVideo = $currentVideo.next();


    $currentVideo.attr('data-state', '');

    if (counter == numVideos) {
        counter = 0;
        $nextVideo = $videos.first();
    }
    $nextVideo.attr('data-state', 'playing');
    $currentVideo.toggleClass('hidden');
    $nextVideo.toggleClass('hidden');

    $currentVideo.find('video')[0].pause();
    $currentVideo.find('video')[0].currentTime = 0;
    $nextVideo.find('video')[0].play();
}, 3000); // do this every 3 seconds    
});
```

And for some reason my HTML and CSS code won't display here (i've added 4 spaces and tried quotations) so, you'll have to look at jsfiddle (see above).

Thanks for helping this noob!

S

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your fiddle and I can see straight away that on Firefox won't work because you are using mp4. You can embed an alternative format for the video and you can use .ogg for firefox and opera.

**Check this MDN resource:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements

```
<video controls>
  <source src="somevideo.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="somevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video in WebM with VP8 or MP4 with H.264.
  <!-- You can embed a Flash player here, to play your mp4 video in older browsers -->
</video>
```

Comment: I think I see the problem in Firefox. My files are named wrong and you're right, I forgot to add webm/ogv. :p

Comment: Yes you added the format on jsfiddle but these files are not present on server at the moment: http://bwpcommunications.com/videobg/001.ogv

Comment: Yep! That worked on Firefox. But still having issues on Safari (Mac OS 10.6.x and iOS). The transitions work but the videos don't show up. @AlexIncarnati

Answer (score 1):

Modified the fiddle a bit. It works on Safari, but to get more support you also need to include webm & ogg.

http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/Z2Nq8/82/

```
var content = [
        ['http://bwpcommunications.com/videobg/001.mp4','Let\'s get together and discuss your brand.'],
        ['http://bwpcommunications.com/videobg/002.mp4','Let\'s build a strategy together face to face.'],
        ['http://bwpcommunications.com/videobg/003.mp4','Let\'s create a compelling campaign and tell your story.']
    ];
    var numVideos = content.length,
        counter = 0,
        $video = $('#bgvid');
        $title = $('#title');
    setInterval(function () {
        ++counter;
        if (counter == numVideos) {
            counter = 0;
        }
        $video.attr('src',content[counter][0]);
        $title.html(content[counter][1]);
    }, 5000); // do this every 3 seconds
```

Comment: Also, how do I add webm and ogv with this code for other browsers? @PhillippWerminghausen

Comment: The deplay is because the video needs to load. And you could use .canPlayType to check for support and then modify the url accordingly.

Comment: But here is another version that also works in safari. It is closer to what you had: http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Nq8/83/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58729/discussion-between-shadna-and-philipp-werminghausen).